# How to get SQL Server scheduled jobs to run while logged out of windows?

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling

I have currently scheduled a job to backup all my database files. I know that the script works because I can manually run the job. I've also scheduled it to run everyday at midnight, and made sure it is enabled.

However, the scheduler does not seem to run while I am logged out. I make it a habit to restart my computer when I leave the office.

This is a strange behaviour because even if I am logged out, I can still access the locally hosted SQL Server database from other computers. This must mean that SQL Server is indeed running... just won't execute scheduled tasks?

What configuration do I need?

Comment: A job scheduled through the SQL Server Agent will run as long as Agent runs, which happens independently of who is and isn't logged in (provided the service is set to start automatically). A scheduled *task* in Windows may not run if you're not logged in, depending on how it's configured. You really want SQL Server Agent do the work here. If you can't (because Agent isn't included in your edition, for example) then your question is really about scheduled tasks in Windows, not SQL Server.

Comment: As long as your SQL Server agent service is running and your particular scheduled job is ENABLED, the job will start at it's scheduled time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone has suggested, I had to make sure that the SQL Server Agent service is running. To get this to run even when logged out, is to set the service to run "automatically".

Computer Management -> Services -> SQL Server Agent -> Right Click/Properties -> Set Startup type to: Automatic.

Now all my jobs run properly logged in or not.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the SQL Server agent is running then the job should run as well.  I would suggest looking at the Properties of the job and check a few things.

Who is listed as OWNER under General?  Does this account have access to run backups?  Under Steps, make sure there is no RUN AS set up.  If there is, does it have the needed access.

Under SQL Server Configuration Manager under SQL Server Services, check what account is shown under SQL Server Agent.  Does it have the needed permission?

BACKUP DATABASE and BACKUP LOG permissions default to members of the sysadmin fixed server role and the db_owner and db_backupoperator fixed database roles.  Make sure the account that is executing the job has the needed permissions.